# Need help on geting the result of count() from db to php

Tags: php

I'm trying to get the count of posts from the db, this is my code:

```html
<?php 
//include config
require_once('../includes/config.php');

//if not logged in redirect to login page
$query = "SELECT COUNT(postId) FROM htdblog_posts";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
echo "Number is: ", $row;
?>
```

Comment: `Number is: Array`  no?  Try `fetch_column` - also `mysql_*` has been removed as of PHP7

Answer (score 0):

```
"SELECT COUNT(postId)  AS postId FROM htdblog_posts"; //check the Alias
echo "Number is: ", $row[0];
```

You return an array so your string value is in the first position

Comment: This is not true in the case of echo, [sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/bbab97bd218a00982107bbccbcf7862bae9e9054) weird I know.  Echo treats it as a function call like this `echo("Number is: ", $row)` or at least you can think of it that way.

Comment: Oh did not know that thanks for pointing it out. Then i guess it's the array field. I will remove my second part of the answer

Comment: Yes the issue is that `mysql_` not `mysqli_`  and `mysql_fetch_row` returns the row as an array, so they need `$row[0]`  I forget as it's been years, but I dont think `mysql_` has a fetch column command which would be ideal.

Comment: `Oh did not know that thanks for pointing it out` It got me the first time I saw it too.

Comment: Last thing is `mysql_fetch_row` does not return associative keys.  so it's just `$row[0]`  http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php  `Returns an numerical array of strings that corresponds to the fetched row, or FALSE if there are no more rows`